# Lavavel Eloquent: Relationships with 5 table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an app consisting of these tables
**users**
id
name

**user_location**
id
user_id
cities_id

**cities**
id
state_id
country_id
name

**states**
id
country_id
name

**countries**
id
name

Then how to get relationship this five table?

Comment: how you are planning to use this models?? we can guess but you should add more context to your question to get an answer. and what have you tried so far??

Comment: There is literally a [whole article about relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) in Laravel in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a many-to-many relationship between tables and use pivot table to show the relationship between table rows using foreignId